# Trying to solve a two-point boundary value problem on MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the following ODE

$$ u'' = -(1 + e^u), u(0)=0, u(1)=1$$

with boundary conditions and $t \in (0,1)$. I want to solve this ODE using the shooting method. First,we convert this to a system of equations. Let $y_1=u, y_2=u'$ and so

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ -(1+e^{y_1}) \end{bmatrix}, \; \; \; \; \begin{bmatrix} y_1(0) \\ y_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ u'(0) \end{bmatrix}$$

Im trying to understand how the shooting method works and hopefully code it in matlab. So,I have to make a guess for $u'(0)$ and then use a ODE solve to get $u(1)=1$. Is this how we procced with this method?

Comment: As you said, make a guess for $u'(0)$. Then, compute the numerical solution $\vec{y_1}$ and see how far is $y_1(N)$ from $1$. Where $y_1(N)$ I mean numerical approximation of $u(1)$ (N is the number of points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you did, you first write the system as

$\begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ -(1+e^{y_1}) \end{bmatrix}, \; \; \; \; \begin{bmatrix} y_1(0) \\ y_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ u'(0) \end{bmatrix}$

in order to use a standard numerical method for ODEs.

So, the goal is to give the right value to $u'(0)$ in order to have $u(1)=1$. In your system, you have to guess the value of $y_2(0)$.

Of course you could do it by hand, but you can actually write a *bisection* method in order to find the correct value for the first derivative. The function you have to set to zero is, actually, $F=y_1(N)-1$.

So, assume to use a numerical method for solving your ODE, say explicit Euler (EE) (for sake of simplicity):

- Consider **two** initial data $y_0= [0,a]^T$, $y_0=[0,b]^T$
- Solve the ODE with (EE) those different initial values. Then you compute, for both the numerical solutions you get $f_a=y_1(N)-1$ and $f_b=y_1(N)-1$.
- Compute the mean of $a,b$, call it $x_m$, and set another initial data $y_0=[0,x_m]^T$, and solve the ODE with (EE) and the last initial data and define $f_m=y_1(N)-1$.
- Apply a standard bisection method: if $f_m \cdot f_a <0$, then $b=x_m$ and $f_b=f_m$, otherwise $a=x_m,f_a=f_m$
- Repet the above procedure until the distance between $a$ and $b$ is $|b-a| \leq 
  \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a chosen tolerance

The following (runable) MatLab code computes the right value for $y_2(0)$, which is approximately $2.4592$.

```
fun=@(t,y) [y(2);-1-exp(y(1))];  
m=200; %time steps
tstar=1;
k=tstar/m;
t = linspace(0,tstar,m+1);
y=zeros(2,m+1);
a=-5;
b=5; % extreme initial points for bisection
iter=0;
maxit=100;
tol=1e-6; %tolerance

while (abs(b-a)>tol) && (iter<maxit)

y(:,1)=[0,a]; %a initial guess iniziale for y2

for n = 1:m
    y(:,n+1) = y(:,n)+k*fun(t(n),y(:,n)); %EE
end
fa=y(1,end)-1; %I have to set to zero F=y(1) - 1. (Want y(1)=1)

y(:,1)=[0,b];

for n = 1:m
    y(:,n+1) = y(:,n)+k*fun(t(n),y(:,n)); %EE
end
fb=y(1,end)-1;    


iter=iter+1;
xm=(a+b)/2;
y(:,1)=[0,xm];

for n = 1:m
    y(:,n+1) = y(:,n)+k*fun(t(n),y(:,n)); %EE
end

fm=y(1,end)-1;


if fa*fm<=0
    b=xm;
    fb=fm;
else 
    a=xm;
    fa=fm;
end

end


disp('The correct value is')
disp(xm)

%%%PLOT THE NUM SOLUTION%%

y=zeros(2,m+1);
y(:,1)=[0,2.4592];
for n = 1:m
     y(:,n+1) = y(:,n)+k*fun(t(n),y(:,n)); %EE
end
plot(t,y(1,:),'-*')
```

The correct numerical solution is the following

[image: numerical solution]

Comment: Another option is to use the secant method which is likely a bit faster.

Comment: Of course, I also know a Newton's method for this type of problem, which is also faster, but I think bisection is a good way to "visualize" the problem

Comment: Once we have $u'(0)$, then we can just use, say Euler's method to find the solution, correct?

Comment: Well, in my specific code I used Euler's method because I didn't want to write much code, but yes, in this simple case you can use Euler with $y_2(0)=2.4592$, and check that actually your numerical solution is one at the boundary $t=1$

Comment: how do you do plots in matlab?

Comment: @ILoveMath You are using whatever ODE IVP solver you want in order to find $u'(0)$ in the first place. So when you are finished you can just retain the solution function instead of discarding it. Also this is not a programming related SE.

Comment: I do plot(t,xm) but it displays blank

Comment: Follow @Ian advice. Anyway, I edited my answer in order to do a plot of the solution

Comment: @ILoveMath of course... $x_m$ is just a number, while $t$ is a vector.

Comment: if we want to use finite difference, how would we discretize the nonlinear term $e^u$?

Comment: @ILoveMath You don't have to. Look at your scheme more carefully; for an ODE IVP solver it does not (structurally) matter whether $f(t,u)$ is linear or nonlinear in a first order system $u'=f(t,u)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195378/using-finite-differences-to-solve-bvp I asked this question as a separate question instead

Comment: @ILoveMath The kind of discretization that you're describing in that thread is not needed in the IVP setting, which is how the shooting method works. You would only need something like that if you wanted to use a more direct BVP method.