# Using finite differences to solve BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the following ODE

$$ u'' = -(1 + e^u), u(0)=0, u(1)=1$$

Using a second order accurate finite difference I obtain

$$ -(1+e^{u_i}) \approx \frac{ u_{i+1} - 2 u_i + u_{i-1} }{h^2} $$

and $u_0 = 0$ and $u_N=1$. Let's say we use mesh size $N$ so we will obtain $N-2$ nonlinear equations for unknowns $u_2,...,u_{N-1}$. Im looking for some help to implement this in Matlab as it would be quite laborious to do it by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the discretization, you end up with $-(1+e^{u_i}) = \frac{ u_{i+1} - 2 u_i + u_{i-1} }{h^2}$, which is equivalent to find the zeros of the vector valued function $F(u_i)=(1+e^{u_i})+ \frac{ u_{i+1} - 2 u_i + u_{i-1} }{h^2}$ where $2\leq  i\leq N-1$

What you are missing is to use a Newton's method in order to solve this *system* of non-linear equations.

Consider the **tridiagonal** matrix which arises from the discretization of the second derivative, say it $A$. (But pay attentio at the boundary conditions, you should modify the first and last row)

Then, you can write $\frac{ u_{i+1} - 2 u_i + u_{i-1} }{h^2}$ as a matrix-vector multiplication $A \cdot \vec{u}$.

With this idea in mind, we rewrite the function $F$ by using that matrix:

---

$F(u)=A\cdot u + \mathbf{1}+e^{\mathbf{u}}$ (note that the RHS is a (N-2)-vector)

Now you just need to use Newton method for the non-linear system, and so you need to compute the Jacobian, which, in this particular case, is

$JF(u)=A+diag(e^u)$

Now just apply Newton's routine and you'll get your numerical solution.

|*EDIT*|

The following runable Octave code show the correct numerical solution (cfr with the previous question)

```
clear all
close all

m=201;
h=1/(m-1);
x=linspace(0,1,m)';
A = toeplitz(sparse([1,2],[1,1],[-2,1]/(h^2),m,1));

F=@(u) [u(1);(A*u+ones(m,1)+exp(u))(2:m-1);u(m)-1];
JF=@(u) [[1,zeros(1,m-1)];(A+diag(exp(u)))(2:m-1,1:m);[zeros(1,m- 
1),1]];
u0=ones(m,1); %Starting guess for newton's method
res=-JF(u0)\F(u0);
tol=h^2/100;
while (norm(res,inf)>tol)
     u0+=res;
        res=-JF(u0)\F(u0);
end
u0+=res;

plot(x,u0,'b-o')
```

[image: Numerical solution with centred FD]

---

|**EDIT**|$^2$

*Note that the following way to impose boundary conditions is in some sense naïf, there are better ways*

In order to write a  runable MatLab code, I modify just the *first and last* rows of the function that we have to set to zero.

First of all define the vector of ones $b=\mathcal{1}$, so the system reads:

$Au+b+e^u=0$ (again, with $e^u$ I mean the vector $[e^{u_1},\ldots,e^{u_n}]$

And, I want to have $u_1=0$. To this aim, I **impose** the first row of the $A$-matrix to have just a $1$ in the (1,1)-position: in this way only $u_1$ survives.

I do this with the command `A(1,1:2)=[1,0]`

Since I have only a dependence on $u$ on the exponential term, I multiply $u$ by an identity matrix $I$, with $I(1,1)=0$, in order to neglect the term $e^{u_1}$. I do this with the command `I(1,1)=0`

So far, the first line is $u_1+ b(1) + e^0=0$, or better:

\begin{align}
u_1+ b(1) + 1=0
\end{align}

Now, I give the first component of $b$ the value I need in order to have $u_1=0$, which is simply $-1$ ! I do this with the command `b(1)=-1`

The first line of the system reads now $u_1 +1-1=0$, hence $u_1=0$, as wanted.

The same reasoning applies to the **last** row, you can see how in the following code.

```
clear all
close all

m=201;
h=1/(m-1);
x=linspace(0,1,m)';
A = toeplitz(sparse([1,2],[1,1],[-2,1]/(h^2),m,1));
I=speye(m); %initialize sparse matrix of size m
b=ones(m,1);
%Boundary conditions
A(1,1:2)=[1,0];
I(1,1)=0; 
b(1)=-1;

A(m,m-1:m)=[0,1];
I(m,m)=0;
b(m)=-2;

%Functions to set to zero and Newton's loop
F=@(u) A*u+b+exp(I*u);
JF=@(u) A+I*diag(exp(I*u));

u0=ones(m,1); %Starting guess for newton's method
res=-JF(u0)\F(u0);
tol=h^2/100;
while (norm(res,inf)>tol)
    u0=u0+res;
    res=-JF(u0)\F(u0);
end
u0=u0+res;
plot(x,u0,'b-o')
```

Comment: Im trying to run this on matlab, but It is not running.

Comment: You should use Octave

Comment: What line of code should we change to make it work ln matlab?

Comment: @ILoveMath Which line raises an error when you try to run it in Matlab?

Comment: The definition of F and JF

Comment: @MikeySpivak It probably doesn't like the indexing of the parenthetical expression (the (2:m-1) on a thing that isn't a named variable). You can define the thing that you're indexing into as a variable in its own right and then index into that.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I dont understand this line of code: JF=@(u) [[1,zeros(1,m-1)];(A+diag(exp(u)))(2:m-1,1:m);[zeros(1,m- 
1),1]];

Comment: how can I write in matlab? what (2:m-1,1:m) means?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in replying, I'm editing my anwert in order to make it runable also in MatLab.  In my Octave code, I'm just working on the internal knots, since the boundary are imposed in the definition of $F$.

Comment: Just edited my answer with a MatLab compatible code

Comment: can you explain this line? A = toeplitz(sparse([1,2],[1,1],[-2,1]/(h^2),m,1)); is this to preallocate the tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: It IS the tridiagonal matrix... try to print it with $m$ equal to a low number.