# Solve non-linear boundary-value-problem with finite difference method (FDM)

Tags: nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

Given a boundary-value-problem

$u''(x) = (10^{-7}u(x) + 10^{-8}x(x-2))\cdot (1 + u'(x)^2)^\frac{3}{2}$

with conditions $u(0) = 0$ and $u(2) = 0$ and formulars for first and second derivation:

$u''(i) = \frac{u_{i-1} - 2u_i + u_{i+1}}{h^2}$ and $u'(i) = \frac{-u_{i-1} + u_{i+1}}{2h}$

As you can see, this differential equation is non-linear.

My professor told me to solve this problem with the `Finite Difference Method (FDM)` using `Newton's Method`.

If the problem were linear, I could have simply set up and solved the system of linear equations. But the nonlinearity poses a challenge that I can not master without a few tips.

Edit:

Please correct me if I am wrong.

So this is the second-order differential equation with the formulas added:

$f_{u_i} = \frac{u_{i-1} - 2u_i + u_{i+1}}{h^2} - (10^{-7}u_i + 10^{-8}x_i(x_i - 2))\cdot (1 + (\frac{-u_{i-1} + u_{i+1}}{2h})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

The diagonal of the Jacobian Matrix is

$\frac{df_{u_i}}{du_i} = -\frac{2}{h^2} - 10^{-7}(1 + (\frac{-u_{i-1} + u_{i+1}}{2h})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} $,

the lower diagonal of the Jacobian Matrix is

$\frac{df_{u_i}}{du_{i-1}} = \frac{1}{h^2} - (10^{-7}u_i + 10^{-8}x_i(x_i - 2))\cdot(1 + \frac{u_{i-1}^2}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i-1}u_{i+1}}{2h} + \frac{u_{i+1}^2}{4h^2})^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{h^2} - \frac{3}{2}(10^{-7}u_i + 10^{-8}x_i(x_i - 2))\cdot(1 + \frac{u_{i-1}^2}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i-1}u_{i+1}}{2h} + \frac{u_{i+1}^2}{4h^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (2\frac{u_{i-1}}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i+1}}{h})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

the upper diagonal of the Jacobian Matrix is

$\frac{df_{u_i}}{du_{i+1}} = \frac{1}{h^2} - (10^{-7}u_i + 10^{-8}x_i(x_i - 2))\cdot(1 + \frac{u_{i-1}^2}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i-1}u_{i+1}}{2h} + \frac{u_{i+1}^2}{4h^2})^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{h^2} - \frac{3}{2}(10^{-7}u_i + 10^{-8}x_i(x_i - 2))\cdot(1 + \frac{u_{i-1}^2}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i-1}u_{i+1}}{2h} + \frac{u_{i+1}^2}{4h^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (2\frac{u_{i+1}}{4h^2} - \frac{u_{i-1}}{h})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write the $i-$th component of this system of non linear equations. Indeed, you want to write $\mathbf{F}(\vec u)=\vec 0$ where $F$ is a vectorial function.

The i-th component of $(F(u))_i$is:

\begin{align}
\frac{u_{i-1} - 2u_i + u_{i+1}}{h^2} - (10^{-7}u_i+10^{-8}x_i (x_i-2))\cdot(1+(\frac{-u_{i-1} + u_{i+1}}{2h})^2)^{3/2}
\end{align}

For each $i \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$ you have to solve $(F(u))_i=0$

As your professor told you, you have to use Newton's method since the equation is non-linear, and so you need the jacobian matrix, and since you have $(F(u))_i$ we can get the i-th *row* of the jacobian, i.e. just compute

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial u_j}, \quad j \in \{1, \ldots,N \}
\end{align}

The only derivatives that are different from zeros are wrt $u_{i-1},u_{i},u_{i+1}$

As an example, if you derive w.r.t to $u_i$ (diagonal term)

\begin{align}
(J)_{ii}=\frac{2}{h^2}-[10^{-7} \cdot (1+(\frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}}{2h})^2)^{3/2}]
\end{align}

You have to compute now $(J)_{i,i+1}$ and $(J)_{i,i-1}$ and then you can build your matrix $J(u)$, which is *tridiagonal* (except to first and last row, because of the boundary conditions)

**But pay attention at the boundary**, they have to be done separately.

Once you have $F$ and $J$, we have just to apply Newton's method for non-linear systems.

Starting with an initial guess $\vec u_o$, compute

\begin{align}
JF(u_k) \delta^k=-F(u_k) \quad \star \\
u_{k+1}=u_k+ \delta^k
\end{align}

until $||\delta^k ||_{\infty} \leq Tol$ where $Tol$ is a tolerance defined

Note that $\star$ is a linear system in $\delta^k$ ($k$ is just an index to underline the fact you're updating the scheme)

Once you have solved the equation, you'll have your solution.

Comment: This actually helped me very much, I didn't find such a good explanation elsewhere on the web. I will edit my question in a few minutes, I would really appreciate it if you could take another look, anyway - thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome. I didn't check all the details, it could be right. I'm sure you can check it by yourself. Now you have to just to build such a jacobian, and you're almost done

Comment: Juse one more question, do you actually solve $JF(u_k)\delta^k = -F(u_k)$ or $J\delta^k=-F(u_k)$ instead ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't unserstand your question: I solve the *linear* system $JF(u_k) \delta^k=-F(u_k)$

Again, note that $F(u_k)$ is a vector, while $JF(u_k) $ is the jacobian matrix that you have to build, and it changes at every iteration (this could be quite expensive actually). A every iteration you solve this linear system to find $\delta^k$

Comment: Try to have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195378/using-finite-differences-to-solve-bvp/3195790#3195790

Comment: What I mean: is $JF(u_k)$ a matrix-vector product? Does this mean I have to multiply the matrix $J$ with the vector of functions $F$?

Comment: No, $JF(u_k)$ is precisely the Jacobian matrix, (which depends on $u$) *evaluated* at the vector $u$. Every element of the jacobian matrix (in principle) is a function of $u$

For a moment, don't think about FD. If you have a vectorial function $F(x,y)=[x^2+y^2,sin(y)+cos(x)]$, its jacobian matrix is 

$J(x,y)=[2x,2y;-sin(x),cos(y)]$ and as you can see it depends on (x,y)